# how can I modify the site packages on heroku because of this error 'PeriodicTask' object has no attribute '_default_manager'

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I am developing my site locally and I was getting an error like this

```
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djcelery/schedulers.py", line 98, in save
 obj = self.model._default_manager.get(pk=self.model.pk)
 AttributeError: 'PeriodicTask' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

so I changed it to this

```
    Model = type(self.model)
    obj = Model._default_manager.get(pk=self.model.pk)
```

I thought that when i did a git heroku push it would change accordingly. But it did not, it only affects the local environment. which makes sense, because heroku uses requirements.txt for the dependencies it downloads into itself. But how can I fix this because it won't work in deployment. I thought I figured it out but that was just locally where it was rectified remotely on heroku is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by modifying original app on git. 
Making clone, modifying it and then adding to requirements.txt this line: git+git://github.com/user/appname@branch_name (you have to use your modified apps url @ branch_name)
This installs your modified app.